# Visual studio 2015 "Не удалось найти подходящий целевой пакет SDK"

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-store

Хочу сделать приложение для Windows Store. У меня лицензионная Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate и лицензионная Windows 8. Когда выбираю этот проект
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то появляется ошибка 
**"Не удалось найти подходящий целевой пакет SDK"**
Хотя при установке vs 2015 Service Pack 3 галочкой отмечал вообще всё.

Comment: У тебя отображается конструктор под Универсальное приложение? Запускается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я устанавливал Windows Software Development Kit (SDK),

[Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk)

[Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk)

[Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: Вот, благодарю. Почему то в гуголе не нашел этих ссылок

Comment: А есть такое же, только для Windows 8.1?

Comment: добавил ссылку для Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ruslan_K прошу прощения, возможно не по теме, но вы случаем знаете, как решить подобную проблему? Подойдут ли данные SDK под мою проблему? Заранее благодарен. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629281/hardware-virtualization-is-disabled-on-this-pc