# UWP - Не отображается конструктор. Требуется более новая версия Windows

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2015

В [прошлый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627487/uwp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF-microsoft-visual-c-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) раз мы узнали, что мне нужно скачать Visual Studio 2015, для работы с ***UWP***. Итак, после скачивания, установки и создания UWP проекта у меня вылез, вот такой вот неприятный момент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как у меня ***Windows 8.1*** и у меня не было выбора устройства ***"локальный компьютер"***, как указано в учебнике из предыдущего вопроса, то я предположил что мне нужно скачать эмулятор под Windows 10 *(?)*.

Итак, я нажимаю скачать эмулятор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И выбираю вот это: *(если я правильно всё понял)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска инсталятора, где-то на *20-40%* загрузки происходит **Error**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглив, я понял, что надо лезть в BIOS моего ноута*(HP)* и что-то там наклацать.

***В чём собственно вопрос:*** Правильными ли шагами я пытаюсь решить данную проблемму с неотображением устройства в конструкторе и препятсвие дальнейшего запуска. Как решить проблему приведённую на последнем скриншоте *(как зайти в биос желательно тоже расписать)*, нужно ли это, что вообще Еррор требует от меня переключить/включить и действительно ли это так необходимо?

Заранее благодарен.

**p.s.** в принципе все ошибки легко гуглятся, но мне интересно именно ваше мнение.

**p.s.s.** снести ОС и перейти на Windows 10 - не предлагать.

***UPDATE:***

После включения Virtualization Technology в BIOS, выскакивает такая ошибка при установке эмулятора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С таким названием (HYPER-V) ничего не устанавливал. Что такое HYPER-V и для чего он нужен?

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас просто выключена виртуализация VT-X в биосе, и ее достаточно включить, это очень-очень часто упоминаемая проблема при работе с виртуальными машинами.

Comment: @etki понимаю, но буду очень благодарен, если бы вы сделали обширный ответ на мой обширный вопрос)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer это опция в биосе. как именно она там называется и где именно расположена - зависит от конкретного биоса. как зайти в биос - зависит от конкретного производителя железа.

Comment: @etki зашёл в биос в разделе конфигураций нашёл строку Virtualization Mod. Сделал активной. Не помогло. Эмулятор до сих пор ругается на еррор.

Comment: @PashaPash  зашёл в биос в разделе конфигураций нашёл строку Virtualization Mod. Сделал активной. Не помогло. Эмулятор до сих пор ругается на еррор.

Comment: найдите как включается vt-x/amd-v конкретно для вашей материнки, следуйте инструкциям

Comment: Проставьте галочки
`Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off` [скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZxXA.png)

Comment: @Ruslan_K у меня нет там галочек для Hyper-V.

Comment: Какая вин8 стоит? Home? Если да, то понятно почему нет Hyper-V. Поставьте  уже 10 pro и всё.

Comment: @MakeMakeluv Пишет Windows 8.1 Single Language.Это Home?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer да, с этой редакцией ничего не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственным решением на данный момент, является переход на ***Windows 10***.